# Software architecture which allows for growth, real life situation

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, asp.net, object-oriented-design

I know of Interfaces, Abstract classes that serve as Base class, I've been reading up on loose coupling, ... But I can't come up with a decent solution when a property of a class changes, and the new type needs to be implemented in other classes using this updated class.

**Example**

Below is a simplified representation of a real life situation. Invoice contains a Contact object which has an Address property.

```
Abstract Class Contact{
    string Name{get;set;}
    string Address{get;set;}
}
```

```
Class Customer:Contact{
    string CustomerNumber{get;set;}
}
```

```
Class Invoice{
    string DocumentNumber{get;set;}
    Customer Customer{get;set;}
}
```

Next, we decide to upgrade the Contact class to contain multiple Addresses. Of which the Invoice will need one.

```
Class Address{
    string Street{get;set;}
}
```

```
Abstract class Contact{
    string Name{get;set;}
    List<Address> Addresses{get;set;}
}
```

Logically, the Invoice class needs to be changed to something like

```
Class Invoice{
    string DocumentNumber{get;set;}
    Customer Customer{get;set;}
    Address InvoiceAddress{get;set;}
}
```

**Problem**

You immediately see that *everywhere* I used the **string** property `Address` before, I will now have to change it to an occurence of the type **Address**

As stated before, this is just a simplified example. The real life problem would be much, much bigger as contacts will be used throughout the entire software.

**Conclusion**

I want to develop the software with a principle that will keep my software light for new versions of certain modules. So that if I decide to create a new Contact module, the impact to the other modules is close to non-existing. So, the added functionality can be implemented gradually.

I want to know how I can tackle such versioning problems. This project is currently still in the architectural design stage, and I want this sorted out before we continue.

Comment: "Programmers - Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development" Tell me how my question fails at that. And Also in the link you provided it states "While long and complete answers are a good thing, questions that would require books to answer completely don't make good questions." Do you think one would need a book to answer my question?  Please be constructive.

Comment: But there **is** an actual question to be solved! Which combination of Interfaces, Abstract classes or properties do I need to use in order to have a minimal impact when a property changes in a class that another class uses. Is my question really _that_ unclear? I mean, can't you see that I took my sweet time to ask my question as complete as possible? I used code samples, devided my question in three chapters. What else do I need to do?!

Comment: @UwConcept: I rephrased your last paragraph to address the concern that @gnat raised. If you don't like it, you could roll it back.`

Comment: Code Complete sec 5.3 design heuristics has some great advice that applies here. Use abstractions, encapsulate implementation details, inherit when it simplifies, hide secrets (that which is hidden, can be changed without breaking code in classes that don't see), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property of a class changes, you have to modify all callers who use that property. Its not possible to magically have an interface change that doesn't require changes to callers who use that interface.

However, you can isolate internal properties from  external interfaces - generally this is as simple as not using getters and setters. They are a true anti=pattern and should be avoided at all times. See, all you are doing by implementing a getter is exposing an internal variable using a method.There's little decoupling or hiding going on. Change the internal variable type.. and you have to change the getter too, which means you have to change all your clients. You might as well make all your members public and cut out the middleman. [See this post](http://thedersen.com/blog/2010/01/20/properties-are-an-anti-pattern/) for more detail.
If you provide true methods that get data from your class, then you can hide the internal variables. If invoice number changes from a string to an int, you can keep the old method that exposed the InvoiceNumber and cast it. Obviously this will not work in every case, but it can help hide the implementation from your callers.

The other thing you can do is implement multiple interfaces on your class, so that old callers can still call the old interface while new ones can access Interface2 or InterfaceEx or whatever.

Comment: This helped me understand the matter best, and even helped me understand the other answer better. So I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Tl;dr use information hiding more.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to develop the software with a principle that will keep my
>   software light for new versions of certain modules. So that if I
>   decide to create a new Contact module, the impact to the other modules
>   is close to non-existing. So, the added functionality can be
>   implemented gradually.

Design your class so that consumers are isolated from the changes, so:

```
class Contact {
  string Address {get; set;} 
}
```

would become

```
class Contact {
  List<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
  Address getAddress() { return Addresses[0].StreetAddressLine; }
}
```

> As stated before, this is just a simplified example. The real life
>   problem would be much, much bigger as contacts will be used throughout
>   the entire software.

Once you see a logical entity more than once across classes, consider extracting it into a class.  The change could have happened once you noticed that address was in both Contact and Invoice, and this would have been fixed before you needed to support multiple addresses.

[Extract Class design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-class)

> I am very curious of the suggestions of other programmers / software
>   architects, and how you tackled versioning problems like these in your
>   projects. This project is currently still in the architectural design
>   stage, and I want this sorted out before we continue.

If you wrote code, and then refactored it, you have moved past the design stage and into implementation.  Consider improvement in the following areas:

1) Designing small components that can be quickly implemented

2) Isolating other components from changes to this component

Do not design for theoretical changes, instead have a development cycle that is short enough to react to change.  If the design and implementation are fairly short, the process of making both the original code and the changed code would have been shorter than combining the two.

Comment: Your answer does help, but how will I know in the `Invoice` class which `Address` of the `Contact` I am using? I would have to alter the `Invoice` class to add a property of type `Address` because the string property Address is no longer valid (because there are now multiple options)

Answer (score 2):

Follow [S.O.L.I.D Design Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and don't be afraid to refactor as soon as you feel the need to. 
Remove unused code, it can make refactoring difficult in the future.

Don't try to build a perfect design at once. Make it work then make it better. Follow [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle): 20% efforts gives 80% of the result.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll look deeper in these principles!